# How do you save files directly to the new iOS11 files app?

Tags: icloud, dropbox-api, ios11

For the app I'm working on, I'm interested in giving the users the ability to save directly to the new [iOS11 Files app](https://developer.apple.com/ipad/#files). The motivation here is that many of our users don't have iCloud set up, nor have any 3rd party cloud services such as Dropbox.

Thus I've been trying to find an API to save directly to the files app -- but haven't been able to find one.

Is this because such an API doesn't exist? In that you don't "read and write to the Files app", rather you "read and write to iCloud/Dropbox/etc" via the service-specific APIs and it *appears* in the Files app?

Answer (score 1):

"Is this because such an API doesn't exist? In that you don't "read and write to the Files app", rather you "read and write to iCloud/Dropbox/etc" via the service-specific APIs and it appears in the Files app?"

This appears to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. According to this [article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/)

1. I created simply test. I added two values into my `plist` file:

[image]

2. Then I saved image into app's sandbox documents dict:

   ```
   let fileManager = FileManager.default
   do {
       let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
       let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test2.png")
       let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel")
       if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
           try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
       }
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```

And that all. Here is a result from my iOS's Files app:

Main page of files app:

[image]

Files saved on device:

[image]

Files saved in my app's sandbox documents dict:

[image]